# Elements loaded via XamlReader() and from MainWindow.Xaml behave differently?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlreader

I have the following Viewbox in MainWindow.Xaml:

```
    <Viewbox x:Name="R1C1Viewbox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1">
      <Border x:Name="R1C1Border" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="3"
                                  BorderThickness="2" Background="White"  
                                  Height="40" Width="40" Margin="0,3,3,0">
        <Grid x:Name="R1C1Grid">
          <TextBlock x:Name="R1C1TextBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" Text="+" FontSize="22"></TextBlock>
          <Polygon x:Name="R1C1LED"
              Points="0,0 15,0 0,15"
              Stroke="#FFED1C24" 
              StrokeThickness="1">
            <Polygon.Fill>
              <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="2.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
              </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Polygon.Fill>
          </Polygon>
          <Button x:Name="R1C1Button" Background="Transparent"
                  BorderBrush="Transparent">
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Border>
    </Viewbox>
```

In my code behind, I define 2 RadialGradientBrushes for the Polygon.Fill property:

```
public static RadialGradientBrush ledOn = new RadialGradientBrush();
public static RadialGradientBrush ledOff = new RadialGradientBrush();


  ledOn.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, .8));
  ledOn.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.White, 0));
  ledOff.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.White, 2.5));
  ledOff.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 0));
```

If I load the viewbox only from MainWindow.xaml, I can use:

```
    R1C1LED.Fill = ledOn;
```

or

```
R1C1LED.Fill = ledOff;
```

and the fill changes as expected. If I load the exact same xaml from a file using XamlReader(), the Viewbox displays exactly as expected but using the code behind to change the fill as above doesn't change the fill and no errors are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
private void OnTest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var xaml =
        @"<Window 
             xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
             xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
             xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008'
             xmlns:mc='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006'
             mc:Ignorable='d'
             Title='WPF App' Height='450' Width='800'>

            <StackPanel Orientation='Vertical'>
                <Button x:Name='R1C1LED' Content='Load Data' />
            </StackPanel>
        </Window>";


    var win = (Window)XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
    var button = (Button)win.FindName("R1C1LED");
    button.Background = Brushes.Red;
    button.Click += (obj, args) => { MessageBox.Show("Hi!"); };
    win.Show();

}
```

Comment: It exists, it just doesn't change. As I said, no errors are generated. If I had tried to assign a value to a null object it would have generated an error. If I use XamlWriter.Save(R1C1LED) generated is the same whether I use FindName or not. The Fill property just doesn't change with R1C1LED.Fill = ledOn.

Comment: I changed answer to show you example what you need to to. Note the absence of `x:Class` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and let you know how it works out. Remember though, my Window already exists as do the elements. I'm just loading new values/properties to each element(viewbox) using Grid.Children.Add(element).